# Major opcode of failed request: 73 (X_GetImage) in Fedora 32 and Fedora 34

Tags: c, x11, fedora

I'm developing an script which can get a screenshot on linux, it should work on ubuntu ,centos and fedora.
The same code ,which can work on ubuntu and centos , throw this error during work on fedora.
Here is the error message:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  73 (X_GetImage)
  Serial number of failed request:  7
  Current serial number in output stream:  7
```

I have tried use XMapRaised() and update my fedora32 to fedora34 ,but it doesn't make any sense.
I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.
Here is the code :

```
Window desktop;
Display* dsp;
XImage* img;

int screen_width;
int screen_height;

dsp = XOpenDisplay(NULL);/* Connect to a local display */

desktop = RootWindow(dsp,0);/* Refer to the root window */

/* Retrive the width and the height of the screen */
screen_width = DisplayWidth(dsp,0);
screen_height = DisplayHeight(dsp,0);

XMapRaised(dsp,desktop);
img = XGetImage(dsp,desktop,0,0,screen_width,screen_height,~0,ZPixmap);
```

Now I even encountered this problem when using XWD, Can't Xlib be used in Fedora?  Here is the error message.

```
    [user@fedora xlibshot]$ xwd -root > myscreen.xwd
  X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  73 (X_GetImage)
  Serial number of failed request:  61
  Current serial number in output stream:  61
```

Comment: Are you using Wayland on the Fedora system?

Comment: @mattdm I don't really know what wayland is, I just download the fedora from official website and  install it on my virtual machine. I didn't make any settings

Comment: @mattdm I found it using Wayland on Fedora, but still no ways to work.